# Using XSLT to remove ALL processing instructions from an XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm transforming an XML document to an HTML one. I'd like to remove every instance of a processing instruction from the source doc.

I've figured out how to remove specific processing instructions via `<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('processing_instruction_name')"/>` but the processing instructions I'm dealing with vary from document to document.

I've tried variations of * for the processing_instruction_name, but my XSL engine keeps throwing parsing errors.  Is what I want to do possible? If so, how do I do it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to create an *empty template* to match all `processing-instruction()` nodes in your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="//processing-instruction()" />
```